# How to fix slider value and return value - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to display the slider's value and also return it so I can use it outside the class. It worked when it was just a grid layout, but when I added it to the screen it stopped working.

It seems like an easy fix, but I can't get my head around it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class SliderMode(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SliderMode, self).__init__(name='slider_m')

        grid_lay = GridLayout(cols=3)
        self.add_widget(grid_lay)

        grip_l = Label(text='Gripper')
        grip_value = Label(text='0')
        grip_slide = Slider(
            min=0,
            max=180,
            value=90,
        )
        grid_lay.add_widget(grip_l)
        grid_lay.add_widget(grip_slide)
        grid_lay.add_widget(grip_value)

        elbow_l = Label(text='Elbow')
        elbow_value = Label(text='0')
        elbow_slide = Slider(
            min=0,
            max=180,
            value=90,
        )
        grid_lay.add_widget(elbow_l)
        grid_lay.add_widget(elbow_slide)
        grid_lay.add_widget(elbow_value)

        grip_slide.bind(value=self.s_value,on_touch_down=update, on_touch_move=update)
        elbow_slide.bind(value=self.s_value,on_touch_down=update, on_touch_move=update)

    def s_value(self, instance, value):
        grip_value.text = str(value)
        elbow_value.text = str(value)

def update(obj, value):
    num = 0
    print("Updating speed to:" + str(obj.value))
    num = obj.value

class MyMain(App):
    def build(self):
        return SliderMode()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMain().run()
```

When it's run, it gives `'grip_value' not defined` and doesn't display or return the value. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with class attributes in python, use `self`.
So in your case:

```
self.grip_value = Label(text='0')
```

And:

```
def s_value(self, instance, value):
    self.grip_value.text = str(value)
    self.elbow_value.text = str(value)
```

Same goes for all the other class attributes in your code.